# How can I hide the info panel on YouTube app?

Tags: youtube

How can I hide the info panels such as the following "WHO covid-19 banner" on YouTube app?

[image]

Link to the video: [click here](https://youtu.be/gAk7aX5hksU)

Information about the info panel giving topical context: [click here](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9004474?hl=en)

Comment: I may be wrong but I don't think it's possible. I see no way to do that even on a rooted device using Vance Magisk module

Comment: Hello Franck. Given the screenshot I believe you are looking for a solution targeting YouTube app. If not, feel free to add the term "mobile website" too. Also, I added relevant link to provide more context about the banner.

Comment: @Firelord got it, thanks for the edit!